# Where is the app.config file in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Where is the app.config file located in VS 2010.

I just can't find this. How can I access it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a template in the [templates directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx) of Visual Studio.

To add a new `app.config`, just righ-click the project, select `Add Item` and find `app.config` in the lists.

Comment: @Failed_Noob - If you mean how to add one to your project, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Oded - No, I need to edit the one I already have. I think when u create a project , an app.config file is implicitly created. I need to edit that file

Comment: @Failed_Noob - And what happens when you double click this file?

Comment: @Oded I need to edit it so that I cude put this <configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: @Failed_Noob - And? What exactly are you having problems with? Open the file and edit it.

Comment: @Oded I am unable to find it , where do u think it is

Comment: @Failed_Noob - Do you have an app.config in your project or not? You are now confusing me with different answers to my questions.

Comment: I can't find any app.config file, If i create one wat should I write in it

Comment: @Failed_Noob - Yes. And when you add an item to the project, you can select an "application configuration" item.

Comment: Can you link me to a sample app.config file

Comment: @Failed_Noob - There is one in visual studio. Add an item to your project. Right click the project, select `Add Item`, find the one for application configuration, and you are good to go.

Comment: @Failed_Noob - This has existed in all versions of VS since 2003.

Comment: This is wat I did : Step 1 http://img18.imageshack.us/i/52782661.png/  Step 2 http://img715.imageshack.us/i/79837801.png/  There is no app config option

Comment: @Failed_Noob - On the left, select `General` instead of `Online Templates`.

Answer (score 4):

Just to improve the precision of Oded's answer, the method for adding a new app.config file to a project is:

Right-click on the project, select Add->New Item..., then select "Application Configuration File" from the list of possible items.